# audio player app for android

Tags: java, android, mp3

hi i have created a new mp3 player app for my owm. In that i am playing songs from a folder where its been stored, the problem is when one song is in play and when i click the next song both gets played, i want the other one to be stopped. the following is my code

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
        {
            Log.e("", "aaaaa "+arg2);

            if(arg2==0)
            {
             mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(aply.this, R.raw.a);
             mplayer.start();
            }
            else
            {               
             mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(aply.this, R.raw.download);
             mplayer.start();
            }

            mplayer.start();
            }
        });
```

pls help me in this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the playing status, if it is playing you have to stop the player and reset the contents and issue the command Play.

```
if (mplayer.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop();
}
mplayer.reset();
mplayer.setDataSource(abs_filepath);//set the path
mplayer.prepare();
mplayer.start();
```

above a sample code

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want a check like this:

```
if (mplayer != null && mplayer.isPlaying()) {
    mplayer.stop();
}
```

at some point before you start your next song?